# GCC compiler cannot be spawned

Tags: gcc

[image]

I was trying to run c program but this problem arise.. I don't know what it's trying to convey.. need help here

Comment: Well, *is* it installed? Where do the error come from? What environment are you using? What operating system? What have you done? What are you trying to do? And if it is installed, *where* is it installed?

Comment: Yes it's installed, I'm using ATOM. I'm using windows, and I first saved in C drive the D drive but both worked but now it making an iissue

Comment: Your GCC may not be included in PATH environment variable like @hien-nguyen 's answer or maybe it needs Admin privilege to run GCC, so try to run ATOM as Administrator

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a pop up from some application rather than GCC. It says that it couldn't find the GCC on your computer, or may be GCC is installed but isn't included in your PATH environment variable.

You can find and install GCC here
https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC